# Object.defineproperty() vs Object.defineproperties()

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm curious why are there available two ways to do seemingly the same thing. Can't I use always defineproperties()? Why use defineproperty() when defineproperties() can handle both single and multiple properties?

Comment: Is it a problem that there alternative ways to achieve the same goal via the API?

Comment: When you want to define just one property, `defineProperty()` takes just slightly less code; so, it's a matter of parsimony.

Comment: I guess using `.defineProperties()` method to define a single property is slighlty less convenient as compared to `.defineProperty()` and using `.defineProperty()` method effectively communicates the idea that you want to define a _single_ property on the object. Same goes for `.defineProperties()` - it effectively communicates the idea that you want to define _multiple_ properties on the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) can't handle multiple properties, it takes the target object, one property name, and one descriptor.

On the other hand, [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) takes the target object, and another object whose every key is a property name and every value is the corresponding descriptor, which allows to define multiple properties at once.

Nothing prevents you from using [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) even for single properties, it's just a bit more work (and maybe less readable code?) because you have to build the object which contains the properties definition.